# How can i check what font the users browser has chosen using javascript?

Tags: javascript, fonts, font-family

Say for example the css on by page for the body element is:

```
font-family: verdana, 'Liberation Sans', sans-serif;
```

How would i be able to check if the users browser is using say 'Liberation Sans'?

I have tried doing something like this:

```
const bodyComputedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(document.body);
const bodyFontFamily = bodyComputedStyle.fontFamily;
console.log('bodyfont: ' + bodyFontFamily);
```

But bodyFontFamily constant will just return a list of all fonts given by the server, which is useless for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this Function.

We can use canvas to detect whether a font is supported.
Draw the detected font and the default font on the canvas, and compare the font symbol dot matrix. Not the same description support.

```
const isSupportFontFamily = (fontFamily) => {
  if (typeof fontFamily != "string") {
    return false;
  }

  const defaultFontFamily = "Arial";
  if (fontFamily.toLowerCase() == defaultFontFamily.toLowerCase()) {
    return true;
  }

  const defaultLetter = "a";
  const defaultFontSize = 100;

  const width = 100,
    height = 100;
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  const context = canvas.getContext("2d", {
    willReadFrequently: true,
  });
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  context.textAlign = "center";
  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.textBaseline = "middle";
  const getFontData = function (fontFamily) {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    context.font =
      defaultFontSize + "px " + fontFamily + ", " + defaultFontFamily;
    context.fillText(defaultLetter, width / 2, height / 2);

    const data = context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height).data;

    return [].slice.call(data).filter(function (value) {
      return value != 0;
    });
  };

  return getFontData(defaultFontFamily).join("") !== getFontData(fontFamily).join("")
};
```

next! we just

```
const bodyComputedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(document.body);
const bodyFontFamily = bodyComputedStyle.fontFamily;
bodyFontFamily.split(', ').find(e => {
    return isSupportFontFamily(e)
})
```

done! that`s it!

Comment: A good answer i guess, but it's a bit bulky for what i' looking for. it's hard to believe there is no standard function in JS to return what font family the browser has chosen. Obviously browsers have that ability now days but there is no simple JS function to reveal it. Who can we contact to tell them to add one? lol

Comment: There would be potential privacy issues if a browser exposed that information.